# MySql slave thinks that the query didn't run on the master, no helpful error

Tags: mysql, bulk-insert, master-slave-replication, gtid

We have a master-slave replication that was running perfectly until recently.
Today i've found the error:

> Query caused different errors on master and slave. Error on master: message (format)='Size of tree cache used in bulk insert optimisation. Note that this is a limit per thread!' error code=126; Error on slave:actual message='no error', error code=0. Default database:'dbname'. Query:'UPDATE table SET something='0', something2='' WHERE something3=4'

We are using GTID based replication.
I tried to skip 1 GTID knowing that the query wasn't important anyway, but it didn't help (the slave sql didn't want to run).
Only setting `ignore_error = 126` worked, but then I turned it off immediately, and another query did the same thing.

The error that the slave shows for the master doesn't seem to be an error, only a documentation for bulk insert optimization.

What's the best way to make the replication work again?

edit: I've executed a problematic query on the master, and it worked.

Comment: Does the table have `INDEX(something3)`?  How many rows are to be updated by that one statement?

Comment: What is value of VARIABLE "tmpdir"?  What filesystems are on the Master?  Are any tight on disk space?  Which version of MySQL?  Was there a bulk-insert at about the same time, especially in the same transaction?

Comment: The table has index on the where query. It was about to update ~700 rows.

`tmp_dir` is at /tmp, which has 500GB free.

Version of master is `5.6.30-log`, of slave is `5.7.18-log`.

I don't think there was another query in that transaction, but there might be in the same time.